# Travelling as mixed indonesian-european unmarried couple in Indonesia and Bali 2023

Tags: legal, hotels, indonesia, religion, bali

I would like to spend some days in Bali with my girlfriend sharing a room, an apartment or a villa. She is Indonesian, I'm European. We have a long-distance relationship and we usually meet in other countries to avoid any issue, but I really would like to visit her home country.

I'm aware of other topics on this matter, but they are very old and I know that recently a new unmarried couple ban has been approved, so I would like to have some updated informations.

Is it still possible somehow? Is the law more enforced now? Of course I know that we have to avoid showing any sign of affection in public.

Thanks!

Comment: "we don't have to show" means "we are not required to show."  I suspect you mean "we have to avoid showing."

Comment: Thank you @phoog

Answer (score 4):

There’s much talk about that new law, but it is not effective yet and once it is, only your or her relatives could start an investigation. I hope you both are on good relations with your parents, so nothing to worry about.

Among all places in Indonesia, Bali is the most liberal. Where is your girlfriend from? She should know that it usually is not a problem in any of the big cities and tourist destinations. Some hotels don’t accept unmarried couples, but that’s it.

Your girlfriend will know which ones to avoid: some hotels bear the name “Syariah Hotel”, and you should not try there (they are not extremists, they just follow islam. guidelines aka no unmarried couples and no alcohol etc).

Don’t be too concerned, unmarried Indonesian couples also need a place to go because you usually cannot stay in your partner’s house overnight.

Comment: Thank you @axel ! She is from South Sumatra but she is relatively new to this kind of problems. I got worried after reading online that police can raid hotels or [something like this](https://www.godsavethepoints.com/bali-indonesia-bans-sex-and-living-together/).

Is there anything I could do to avoid being rejected by an hotel? Like, I'm worried to book the hotel (not Syariah) on Agoda or Booking, then go there and being rejected.

Comment: I have never had problems like that. I think those raids are usually made on the kind of hotel that your girlfriend would avoid anyway.When in Indonesia I usually use Traveloka, also to book domestic flights and trains.